# How to change the name of some code statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm now looking up this simple question for hours on google and I think it will be easier to ask hier!

I want to rename a code statement so that i would use let's say a french version of python!
In that case I wont write

```
print ("hello to everyone")
```

but i would write

```
ecrire ("bonjour à tous")
```

But hier comes the problem, I need to redefine (i guess it's the term) the code statement and something like this wont work:

```
ecrire = print
```

Thank you!

Comment: In Python 3 that will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You approach can be done for the built-in functions but not for the statements (`if`, `for`, `else`) and so on. So you're restricted in what you can easily translate to French text.

It's in theory possible to modify the CPython source, change all relevant strings to French and recompile it but that's a lot more work.

Comment: Or put a DSL compiler in front as Ren'Py does.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: ah yes, compiling your own language to Python is also possible. It's not really Python anymore but at first sight it would work as if you were programming in a French version of Python.